# Extracting Values from Array in Redshift SQL

Tags: sql, regex, amazon-redshift, mode-analytics

I have some arrays stored in Redshift table "transactions" in the following format:

```
id, total, breakdown
1, 100, [50,50]
2, 200, [150,50]
3, 125, [15, 110]
...
n, 10000, [100,900]
```

Since this format is useless to me, I need to do some processing on this to get the values out. I've tried using regex to extract it.

```
SELECT regexp_substr(breakdown, '\[([0-9]+),([0-9]+)\]')
FROM transactions
```

but I get an error returned that says

```
Unmatched ( or \(
Detail: 
-----------------------------------------------
error:  Unmatched ( or \(
code:      8002
context:   T_regexp_init
query:     8946413
location:  funcs_expr.cpp:130
process:   query3_40 [pid=17533]
--------------------------------------------
```

Ideally I would like to get x and y as their own columns so I can do the appropriate math. I know I can do this fairly easy in python or PHP or the like, but I'm interested in a pure SQL solution - partially because I'm using an online SQL editor (Mode Analytics) to plot it easily as a dashboard.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

If `breakdown` really is an array you can do this:

```
select id, total, breakdown[1] as x, breakdown[2] as y
from transactions;
```

If breakdown is *not* an array but e.g. a `varchar` column, you can cast it into an array if you replace the square brackets with curly braces:

```
select id, total, 
       (translate(breakdown, '[]', '{}')::integer[])[1] as x,
       (translate(breakdown, '[]', '{}')::integer[])[2] as y
from transactions;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
SELECT REPLACE(SPLIT_PART(breakdown,',',1),'[','') as x,REPLACE(SPLIT_PART(breakdown,',',2),']','') as y FROM transactions;
```

I tried this with redshift db and this worked for me.

**Detailed Explanation:**

- `SPLIT_PART(breakdown,',',1)` will give you `[50`.
- `SPLIT_PART(breakdown,',',2)` will give you `50]`.
- `REPLACE(SPLIT_PART(breakdown,',',1),'[','')` will replace the `[` and will give just `50`.
- `REPLACE(SPLIT_PART(breakdown,',',2),']','')` will replace the `]` and will give just `50`.

Comment: Solved my issue in Redshift with data_type as a character varying. Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Know its an old post.But if someone needs a much easier way

```
select json_extract_array_element_text('[100,101,102]', 2);
```

output : 102